# php file_get_contents encoding issue

Tags: php, encoding, sms

I am trying to Integrate an SMS service into my website. I need to make a HTTP call with a param named "msg" (urlencoded).

Currently, I am constructing the entire URL with msg param being urlencoded (i.e `$msg = urlencode($msg)`), and I am sending the SMS.

```
$msg = urlencode("Hello World");
```

Although what I receive on my phone is "Hello+World" and NOT "Hello World".

So is there an issue with `file_get_contents` ?

Also, is there anyway, I can see the string "file_get_contents" finally sends out ?

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to urlencode it? Because this will replace every spaces with a plus sign. It serves to make valid urls. Not send a text message. Have you tried without it?

Comment: I am supposed to urlecode the "msg" param. 
rawurlecode did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what was the issue:

I was using [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) to create the query string, and I was passing a [`urlencode`](http://php.net/urlencode)'d param to it. Hence it was being encoded twice.

> So is there an issue with `file_get_contents` ?

No.

> Also, is there any way, I can see the string `file_get_contents` finally sends out ?

Yes, with a network sniffer.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php) instead.

The principal difference (although there are others) is that it encodes spaces as `%20` instead of `+`. This is quite likely the source of your problem.

Comment: What happens now? Do you get `Hello%20World`?

Comment: Please can you show the full code you have used to generate the request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use urldecode() after retrieving data and then display to user